# Use data from a scope outside of the scope

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to use a text from a website in an iPhone app. To do that I use a web **scraper** , [Osmosis](https://github.com/ChristianPraiss/Osmosis). I managed to retrieve the data I wanted but I can't affect the data to an array, in order to use it outside of the function. Here's a snippet of what I did:

<language: lang-swift>

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var quote: UILabel!
    
    private var array: [[String: AnyObject]] = []
    

    var initArray: [[String: AnyObject]] {
        get {
            return array
        }
        set {
            for e in self.initArray {
                array.append(e)
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
        getQuotes()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    func getQuotes()
        
        Osmosis(errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
            print(error)
        })
            .get(NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com")!)
            .find(OsmosisSelector(selector: ".parentDiv"), type: .CSS)
            .populate([
                OsmosisPopulateKey.Single("quotes") : OsmosisSelector(selector: ".childDiv")
                ], type: .CSS)
            .list { (dict) -> Void in
                self.array.append(dict)
                print(self.initArray) // this prints data
            }
            .start()
        print(self.initArray) // This prints an empty array
    }
}
```

I think I can't use the array because it is filled inside the init of `Osmosis()` but I wonder how to use it somewhere else in my code. Can you please explain what happens in my code (why can I use the data only in `.list()`) and how to fix that.

**Edit:**
I tried to use a getter and a setter in order to retrieve my data outside of the scope, but the result is the same as if there were no getter/setter.

Comment: I know my title is not explicit at all, but I have no idea how to be more precise. If you find a better title, please go ahead and change it. Cheers

Comment: One issue you have is that your `array` is of type `[[String: AnyObject]]` and your `quotesArray` is of the same type, but you try to append `array` to `quotesArray`: it can't work. If you want to append an array of dictionaries to a new container array, this container should be of type `[[[String: AnyObject]]]` but I'm not sure this is really what you want to do...

Comment: Another issue is that `print(self.array)` is *outside the scope of the Osmosis closure* so you're looking at it while it's not populated *yet* so you think it's empty. Put `print(self.array)` inside the `.list` block instead, just before the closing brace, in the empty line.

Comment: thanks for your answer @EricD. I know printing my array inside of the scope will work but my goal is to use the data outside of the scope.

Comment: I tried to change the type of quotesArray to `[[[String: AnyObject]]]` but when I print it it prints an empty array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Christian Dietrich's answer and comments, I managed to fix my issue by updating the UI inside my scope.

Here's what I did:

```
import UIKit
import Osmosis

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var quote: UILabel!

    var array: [[String: AnyObject]] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        getQuotes()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func getQuotes() {

        var updateText: String = ""

        Osmosis(errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
            print(error)
        })
            .get(NSURL(string: "http://www.exemple.com")!)
            .find(OsmosisSelector(selector: ".wrapper"), type: .CSS)
            .populate([
                OsmosisPopulateKey.Single("div") : OsmosisSelector(selector: ".div")
                ], type: .CSS)
            .list { (dict) -> Void in
                self.array.append(dict)
                updateText = self.array[0]["div"] as! String
                self.quote.text = updateText
                self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
            }
            .start()
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

you want to add all elements of one array to another array?

```
for e in quotesArray {
    self.array.append(e)
}
```

or

```
self.array.appendContentsOf(quotesArray)
```

Comment: I want indeed to add elements of `array` to `quotesArray`. I tried both your solutions but it prints an empty array...

Comment: are you sure your api is NOT async? did you add the print right after the append?

Comment: My guess is that the api IS async and I print outside of the scope, since I want my data to be available everywhere.

Comment: you have to put all logic that depends on the result of the calcuation AFTER the calculation is done. does the print has to be inside .list

Comment: By putting the logic after the calculation is done, you mean that I have to populate my array outside of the Osmosis scope ? If this is what you mean, I tried to do it, but it returns an empty array.

Comment: i dont know Osmosis. the question is: when do you read your array. at the point you read it now it is not yet populated. thus you need to e.g. to update the ui inside the list closure ?!? if the closure is async outside the main thread you may have to wrap the into a dispatch_async on the main_queue - so what happens if you move  print(self.array) into the list

Comment: if I move the `print(self.array )` into the list it prints the data correctly. But if it's not, it print an empty array.

Comment: yes but then you should trigger your processing of the data at exactly that point e.g. by calling the view to refresh (self.view.setNeedsDisplay)